# Optimizing MongoDB query with 1 : n relationship

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, foreach, query-optimization

I wrote some functional code and I wonder how I can improve this snippet. Currently I make two calls to the database and I wonder if I can merge these in a clean way using aggregation, mongoose forEach method or any other ideas!

I have two table with a One-To-Many relation ship: Users and days. Users can have many days and each day have only one user. I want to create an unique day for every users and push it into the embedded data array because I will store user informations into each day object.

**User n:1 Day**

```
 User.find().then
(
   students => {
     for(let student of students){
       const newDay = new Day({
         date: moment().format("YYYY MM DD"),
       });
       newDay.save();
       User.findOneAndUpdate({_id: student.id},{'$push':{data: newDay.id}})
       .then
       (
         () => {
           console.log("Success");
         }
       );
     }
   }   
)
```

This code is working but I'm not sure at all to follow the best practices.

Comment: This code creates `Day` per each user, so day is not unique

Answer (score 0):

You may add new `Day` for each `User` this way:

```
new Day({
   date: moment().format("YYYY MM DD")
}).save().then((newDay) => {
    User.updateMany({}, {'$push':{data: newDay.id}})
        .then(() => {
            console.log("Success");
        });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But this way will put the new day into every users. My need is different, I want to create an unique day for each user. Thank you for your support

Comment: @EelkeJohnson it is Many-To-Many in this case. Suppose: user1 - day1(1), user2 - day1(2). What's is the difference between day1(1) and day1(2)?

Comment: Everyday have an unique ID, every user have an array data who store unique day Ids. So, when I create a day, it should be unique to the user. Because I'll store user's data into the day object. So every day have only 1 user and a user can have many days.

Comment: @EelkeJohnson please update your question, you sample code doesn't mention this statement: `I'll store user's data into the day object.`